# Can not change permissions on FTP for files created with PHP copy

Tags: php, ftp, file-permissions, chmod

I have a script that uses the `copy` function of PHP to copy files to my server. When I log into my server via FTP I can't delete them anymore, as the permissions are set to 644. But when I try to change the permissions directly at the FTP, I get a "Operation not permitted" error.

```
NOOP
200 NOOP command successful
SITE CHMOD 777 /test2/2016-07-19/13739536_1750492681870132_416621053_n.jpg
550 CHMOD 777 /test2/2016-07-19/13739536_1750492681870132_416621053_n.jpg: Operation not permitted
```

Normally I can change the permissions on my server without any problems. Via SSH it is also not working. Does it have to do something with the permissions of the original file?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP script is a different user than the one that is logging in through FTP.

Either change the permisions of the file using another php script or log in as root through SSH.

Comment: Hey Michal, sorry for the late reply, I was lost in other occuring problems ;)

Unfortunately there is no progress. I changed the permissions of the file with PHP to 777. But I still can’t delete it with FTP. 

But I saw that the folder of the files still has not the right permissions. I will check that again today.

Comment: That is the problem. :) If you create file with PHP script you can edit / delete it only with php script. Unless you have root privileges in SSH. Then you can log in to SSH as root and delete the file. Think of PHP, FTP and SSH as three different people. SSH can do anything (if he is a root), FTP can modify only his files and PHP can also modify only his files.

Comment: Then this might be my problem, thanks! I will check it and will let you know if it works. Thanks already for your help!

Comment: Great, thanks, it works. Now I used PHP to change the permissions of the folders that I created with PHP. Then I was able to delete the folder within my FTP client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an error with the argument supplied..
This should normally work

```
chmod("/test2/2016-07-19/13739536_1750492681870132_416621053_n.jpg",0777);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried to directly change the permissions in my FTP client. I also tried it with SSH, both was not working.